# Existing Custom Rally App is producign results as expected

Tags: rally

I got the below reference of CustomHTML App for Rally and added into my custom report page in my project workspace. UI Worked, but somehow whatever simple query I give in, there is no result shown. Please review and correct me if I am doing any wrong.
    
    
    
    Find fixed defects within certain dates

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0rc1/sdk.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Rally.onReady(function() {
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
extend: 'Rally.app.App',
componentCls: 'app',
layout: {
type: 'vbox',
align: 'stretch'
},
items:[
{
xtype: 'panel',
layout: 'anchor',
border: true,
fieldDefaults: {
labelWidth: 40
},
defaultType: 'textfield',
bodyPadding: 5,
items: [
{
fieldLabel: 'Query',
itemId: 'queryField',
anchor:'100%',
width: 700,
height: 100,
xtype: 'textarea',
value: '{\n'+
' "_TypeHierarchy": "Defect",\n'+                  
'"__At": "2016-10-14T00:00:00Z"'+
'}'
},
{
fieldLabel: 'Fields',
itemId: 'fieldsField',
anchor: '100%',
width: 700,
value: "ObjectID, _ValidFrom, Name, State, Resolution"
},
{
fieldLabel: 'Sort',
itemId: 'sortField',
anchor: '100%',
width: 700,
value: "{'ObjectID' : -1, '_ValidFrom': 1}"
},
{
fieldLabel: 'Page Size',
itemId: 'pageSizeField',
anchor: '100%',
width: 700,
value: '10'
    },
{
fieldLabel: 'Hydrate',
itemId: 'hydrate',
anchor: '100%',
width: 700,
value: "State, Resolution"
    },
],

buttons: [
    {
xtype: 'rallybutton',
text: 'Search',
itemId: 'searchButton'
    }
]
    },
    {
xtype: 'panel',
itemId: 'gridHolder',
layout: 'fit',
height: 400
    }
],
launch: function() {
    var button = this.down('#searchButton');
    button.on('click', this.searchClicked, this);
},

searchClicked: function(){
    var queryField = this.down('#queryField');
    var query = queryField.getValue();

    var selectedFields = this.down('#fieldsField').getValue();
    if(selectedFields){
if(selectedFields === 'true'){
    selectedFields = true;
}
else{
    selectedFields = selectedFields.split(', ');
}
    }

    var sort = this.down('#sortField').getValue();

    var pageSize = this.down('#pageSizeField').getValue();
    var parsedPageSize = parseInt(pageSize, 10);
    // don't allow empty or 0 pagesize
    pageSize = (parsedPageSize) ? parsedPageSize : 10;

    var callback = Ext.bind(this.processSnapshots, this);
    this.doSearch(query, selectedFields, sort, pageSize, callback);
},

createSortMap: function(csvFields){
    var fields = csvFields.split(', ');
    var sortMap = {};
    for(var field in fields){
if(fields.hasOwnProperty(field)){
    sortMap[field] = 1;
}
    }

    return sortMap;
},

doSearch: function(query, fields, sort, pageSize, callback){
    var transformStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore', {
context: {
    workspace: this.context.getWorkspace(),
    project: this.context.getProject()
},
fetch: fields,
find: query,
autoLoad: true,
    hydrate: ["State","Resolution"],
listeners: {
    scope: this,
    load: this.processSnapshots
}
    });
},

processSnapshots: function(store, records){
    var snapshotGrid = Ext.create('Rally.ui.grid.Grid', {
title: 'Snapshots',
store: store,
columnCfgs: [
    {
text: 'ObjectID',
dataIndex: 'ObjectID'
    },
    {
text: 'Name',
dataIndex: 'Name'
    },
    {
text: 'Project',
dataIndex: 'Project'
    },
    {
text: '_ValidFrom',
dataIndex: '_ValidFrom'
    },
    {
text: '_ValidTo',
dataIndex: '_ValidTo'
    },
{
text: 'State',
dataIndex: 'State'
    },
{
text: 'Resolution',
dataIndex: 'Resolution'
    },
],
height: 400
    });
var gridHolder = this.down('#gridHolder');
}
gridHolder.removeAll(true);
gridHolder.add(snapshotGrid);
});

Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
    name: 'lbapi'
});
    });
    </script>

<style type="text/css">
.app {
 /* Add app styles here */
}
    </style>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple syntax errors in the posted code above.  It was also written using a super old version of the sdk.  I updated to the latest 2.1 and it seems to work pretty well now.  More than likely most of the issues with the old app was the Lookback API request timing out.  The new SDK has a longer default timeout.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Lookback API Query</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.1/sdk.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Rally.onReady(function() {
            Ext.define('CustomApp', {
                extend: 'Rally.app.App',
                componentCls: 'app',
                layout: {
                    type: 'vbox',
                    align: 'stretch'
                },
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    layout: 'anchor',
                    border: true,
                    fieldDefaults: {
                        labelWidth: 40
                    },
                    defaultType: 'textfield',
                    bodyPadding: 5,
                    items: [{
                        fieldLabel: 'Query',
                        itemId: 'queryField',
                        anchor: '100%',
                        width: 700,
                        height: 100,
                        xtype: 'textarea',
                        value: '{\n' +
                            ' "_TypeHierarchy": "Defect",\n' +
                            '"__At": "2016-10-14T00:00:00Z"\n' +
                            '}'
                    }, {
                        fieldLabel: 'Fields',
                        itemId: 'fieldsField',
                        anchor: '100%',
                        width: 700,
                        value: "ObjectID, _ValidFrom, Name, State, Resolution"
                    }, {
                        fieldLabel: 'Sort',
                        itemId: 'sortField',
                        anchor: '100%',
                        width: 700,
                        value: "{'ObjectID' : -1, '_ValidFrom': 1}"
                    }, {
                        fieldLabel: 'Page Size',
                        itemId: 'pageSizeField',
                        anchor: '100%',
                        width: 700,
                        value: '10'
                    }, {
                        fieldLabel: 'Hydrate',
                        itemId: 'hydrate',
                        anchor: '100%',
                        width: 700,
                        value: "State, Resolution"
                    }, ],

                    buttons: [{
                        xtype: 'rallybutton',
                        text: 'Search',
                        itemId: 'searchButton'
                    }]
                }, {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    itemId: 'gridHolder',
                    layout: 'fit',
                    height: 400
                }],
                launch: function() {
                    var button = this.down('#searchButton');
                    button.on('click', this.searchClicked, this);
                },

                searchClicked: function() {
                    var queryField = this.down('#queryField');
                    var query = queryField.getValue();

                    var selectedFields = this.down('#fieldsField').getValue();
                    if (selectedFields) {
                        if (selectedFields === 'true') {
                            selectedFields = true;
                        } else {
                            selectedFields = selectedFields.split(', ');
                        }
                    }

                    var sort = this.down('#sortField').getValue();

                    var pageSize = this.down('#pageSizeField').getValue();
                    var parsedPageSize = parseInt(pageSize, 10);
                    // don't allow empty or 0 pagesize
                    pageSize = (parsedPageSize) ? parsedPageSize : 10;

                    var callback = Ext.bind(this.processSnapshots, this);
                    this.doSearch(query, selectedFields, sort, pageSize, callback);
                },

                createSortMap: function(csvFields) {
                    var fields = csvFields.split(', ');
                    var sortMap = {};
                    for (var field in fields) {
                        if (fields.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
                            sortMap[field] = 1;
                        }
                    }

                    return sortMap;
                },

                doSearch: function(query, fields, sort, pageSize, callback) {
                    var transformStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore', {
                        context: {
                            workspace: this.context.getWorkspace(),
                            project: this.context.getProject()
                        },
                        fetch: fields,
                        pageSize: pageSize,
                        find: query,
                        autoLoad: true,
                        hydrate: ["State", "Resolution"],
                        listeners: {
                            scope: this,
                            load: this.processSnapshots
                        }
                    });
                },

                processSnapshots: function(store, records) {
                    var snapshotGrid = Ext.create('Rally.ui.grid.Grid', {
                        title: 'Snapshots',
                        store: store,
                        columnCfgs: [{
                            text: 'ObjectID',
                            dataIndex: 'ObjectID'
                        }, {
                            text: 'Name',
                            dataIndex: 'Name'
                        }, {
                            text: 'Project',
                            dataIndex: 'Project'
                        }, {
                            text: '_ValidFrom',
                            dataIndex: '_ValidFrom'
                        }, {
                            text: '_ValidTo',
                            dataIndex: '_ValidTo'
                        }, {
                            text: 'State',
                            dataIndex: 'State'
                        }, {
                            text: 'Resolution',
                            dataIndex: 'Resolution'
                        }, ],
                        height: 400
                    });
                    var gridHolder = this.down('#gridHolder');
                    gridHolder.removeAll(true);
                    gridHolder.add(snapshotGrid);
                }
            });

            Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
                name: 'lbapi'
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .app {
            /* Add app styles here */
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body></body>

</html>
```